# Fine-tuning from ./checkpoints/ssd_300_vgg.ckpt. Ignoring missing vars: False

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, object-detection

i want to train SSD for num_classes=2 . link of this code is [here](https://github.com/balancap/SSD-Tensorflow) . I write this code in command prompt:

```
python train_ssd_network.py \
    --train_dir=./logs/ \
    --dataset_dir=./tfrecords\
    --dataset_name=pascalvoc_2012 \
    --dataset_split_name=train \
    --model_name=ssd_300_vgg \
    --checkpoint_path=./checkpoints/ssd_300_vgg.ckpt \
    --save_summaries_secs=60 \
    --save_interval_secs=600 \
    --weight_decay=0.0005 \
    --optimizer=adam \
    --learning_rate=0.001 \
    --batch_size=32
```

but I got this error :

```
    start_standard_services=start_standard_services)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\supervisor.py", line 706, in prepare_or_wait_for_session
    init_feed_dict=self._init_feed_dict, init_fn=self._init_fn)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\session_manager.py", line 264, in prepare_session
    init_fn(sess)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\framework\python\ops\variables.py", line 655, in callback
    saver.restore(session, model_path)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1457, in restore
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 778, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 982, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1032, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1052, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [12] rhs shape= [126]
         [[Node: save_1/Assign_29 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@ssd_300_vgg/block8_box/conv_cls/biases"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](s
sd_300_vgg/block8_box/conv_cls/biases, save_1/RestoreV2_29)]]

Caused by op 'save_1/Assign_29', defined at:
  File "train_ssd_network.py", line 390, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "train_ssd_network.py", line 378, in main
    init_fn=tf_utils.get_init_fn(FLAGS),
  File "F:\Downloads\SSD-Tensorflow-master-\tf_utils.py", line 235, in get_init_fn
    ignore_missing_vars=flags.ignore_missing_vars)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\framework\python\ops\variables.py", line 653, in assign_from_checkpoint_fn
    saver = tf_saver.Saver(var_list, reshape=reshape_variables)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1056, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1086, in build
    restore_sequentially=self._restore_sequentially)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 691, in build
    restore_sequentially, reshape)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 419, in _AddRestoreOps
    assign_ops.append(saveable.restore(tensors, shapes))
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 155, in restore
    self.op.get_shape().is_fully_defined())
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\state_ops.py", line 270, in assign
    validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_state_ops.py", line 47, in assign
    use_locking=use_locking, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [12] rhs shape= [126]
         [[Node: save_1/Assign_29 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@ssd_300_vgg/block8_box/conv_cls/biases"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](s
sd_300_vgg/block8_box/conv_cls/biases, save_1/RestoreV2_29)]]
```

can Somebody help me why...according to some guidance I changed checkpoint_path=./checkpoints/ssd_300_vgg.ckpt to checkpoint_path=./checkpoints/ssd_300_vgg.ckpt/ssd_300_vgg.ckpt, but I get error too.

Answer (score 0):

You should define "checkpoint_exclude_scopes ",if you want to fine-tuning a network trained on ImageNet.
More detail described in the SSD-Tensorflow [README.md](https://github.com/balancap/SSD-Tensorflow)